# Angularjs won't work with my google app engine configuration

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine

I include google's angularjs scripts but they don't seem to work with the app. If I open the html webpage directly with an internet browser it works fine. 
The page is just a simple test with ng-model to see what you are typing and it doesn't print {{name}}

```
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

this is the app:

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get (self, q):
        if q is None:
            q = 'index.html'
        path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
        self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

def main ():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main ()
```

this is my app.yaml

```
application: sixth-tribute-676
version: 2
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not very useful, can you be more specific?

Comment: What does the console log say? Anything about files not found or similar?

Comment: No, only a GET for the stylesheet and the html file

Comment: Did you load your url with https? the browser might be complaining you're loading the angular resource with http and block it. You can see this in browser console log

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using `template.render` and `{{name}}` disappeared. I should serve the html without rendering it.